# Make TreeViewItem control execute command when double clicked

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, command, treeviewitem

I'm looking for a way, in WPF, to bind commands to a TreeViewItem, so when I double click a TreeViewItem a ICommand is executed in my ViewModel (MVVM pattern).
Much like the  Visual Studio Solution Explorer.

I was hoping that I could use something like [AttachedCommandBehaviour](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/) but that does not work. I guess it's because that the TreeViewItem itself does not support Commands.

Here is my test implementation which doesn't work:

```
<TreeViewItem Header="Opret produktions ordre">
    <acb:CommandBehaviorCollection.Behaviors>
        <acb:BehaviorBinding Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" Command="{Binding TestCommand}"/>
    </acb:CommandBehaviorCollection.Behaviors>
</TreeViewItem>
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to make this work? Or maybe you know of a control that give me this functionality?
I am of course hoping for a MVVM friendly solution. Preferably all in XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `InvokeDataCommand` trigger from the [CodePlex Expression Blend sample library](http://expressionblend.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Behaviors%20and%20Effects&referringTitle=Documentation)?

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
      <si:InvokeDataCommand Command="{Binding ShoppingCart.CheckOutCommand}"/>
</i:EventTrigger>
```

You will need the fixed version though if you're using WPF4, read about the issue here: http://blog.thekieners.com/2010/11/09/expression-blend-samples-not-working-with-silverlight-4-and-wpf-4/

Download the sample solution from here (this is the updated version): http://expressionblend.codeplex.com/workitem/8148

Comment: Their documentation is pretty poor. Do you have an example?

Comment: Make sure you download the sample solution, adding the right link. I found the example in the sample library pretty self-explanatory, also adding to my answer as a starting point, but do let me know if / where you need more info!

Comment: I have a compilation problem that you might be able to assist me with. The Expression.Samples.Interactivity has a dependency on System.Windows v2.0.50727. When I reference the Expression.Samples.Interactivity assembly in my project, and use the InvokeDataCommand I get a compile error saying that it cannot resolve the dependency to assembly System.Windows. Any idea? Seems like a left-over from WPF2.

Comment: Have you got Expression Blend 4 installed? If not, you might have to download the Expression SDK. Otherwise not sure :)

Comment: I'm not sure I want my solution to depend on that :) And I do not want to include WPF2 binaries. There must be another solution.

Comment: What's wrong with having the SDK installed if you don't want Blend itself (it's really great though)? You won't be able to use behaviors and triggers otherwise! It's a 4.2MB download: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d197f51a-de07-4edf-9cba-1f1b4a22110d&displaylang=en

Comment: That's really strange, not sure why / if you have to have v2 libraries. Have you downloaded the latest Expression SDK? Also have you downloaded the updated Blend examples which I linked? I think the original ones were indeed made for v2 Silverlight / WPF, but those latest ones in the last link worked for me perfectly with Silverlight 4. Or maybe you have an older Expression SDK installed for some reason bundled with something, which you have to remove or make sure that you explicitly include the v4 libraries?

Comment: I have the latest Expression SDK installed. I just double checked. I'm using the library that you linked to here (the file attachment): http://expressionblend.codeplex.com/workitem/8148

Comment: I'm running out of ideas what could be the issue. Does that example solution work if you try to run it?

Comment: Is [this](http://expressionblend.codeplex.com/workitem/8148) the example solution you're referring to? If so, it's not a runnable GUI application that I can test. I can compile it though.

Comment: Yeah, that one. If that compiles though then the issue might be with how you're trying to import it to your project? In my case I just grabbed the source for the classes I actually needed (and the dependencies), updated the class package paths and used it that way from my project internally. Are you trying to import the assembly?